# Large number of data export into CSV - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

So I have this CI Project that converts from database(with large numbers of data) into CSV.

I try to export all data, after I click the "Convert to CSV", It will take so much time loading and the browser will give me a Time-out error.

Here is the code for the export function:

```
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        set_time_limit(-1);

        $prefKey = $this->session->flashdata('prefKey');
        $searchKey = $this->session->flashdata('searchKey');
        $withEmail = $this->session->flashdata('withEmail');

        $list = $this->user_model->get_users($prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, "", "");

        $headerArray = array("id", "prefecture_id", "industry_id", "offset", "name", "email");

        // Header
        $header = str_replace(",", "", $headerArray);
        $datas = implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";

        // Body
        foreach($list as $body)
        {

            $orig_email = $body['email'];

            $mstring = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/",',',$orig_email);

            preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $mstring, $matches);
            $email = implode($matches[0]);

            $datas .= $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$body["offset"].",".preg_replace('/[,]/',' ',$body["name"]).",".$email."\r\n";
        }

        $datas = mb_convert_encoding($datas, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8");

        $csvFileName = "phpList_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".csv";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $csvFileName);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        ob_start();
        print trim($datas);
        ob_flush();
        ob_end_clean();
        exit;
```

the settings for the php.ini are the following:

```
max_execution_time = 259200
max_input_time = 259200
memory_limit = 2G
```

Still same error.

I cannot determine where does it stop/time-out. Is it when from querying the data? Putting the datas in CSV? or Downloading?

From the code provided above, how can I do like a by-batch process? I think this is just a one-time process.

This is the Model:

```
public function get_users($prefecture_id, $industry_id, $filter, $limit, $start){ 

        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('company'); 

        if ($filter) {
            $this->db->like('email','@');
        }

        if (!empty($prefecture_id) && $prefecture_id != 99) {
            $this->db->where('prefecture_id', $prefecture_id);
        }

        if (!empty($industry_id) && $industry_id != 99) {
            $this->db->where('industry_id', $industry_id);
        }

        if (!empty($limit)) {

            $this->db->limit($limit, $start); 
        }
        $this->db->order_by('prefecture_id, industry_id, offset');
        $query = $this->db->get(); 

        $result =  $query->result_array(); 

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Check the max_execution_time in php.ini, also please turn on the error_reporting

Comment: @DavinderKumar those settings are set to large. Still getting the time-out.

Comment: how many users do you've in your db ?

Comment: @sintakonte users? you mean how many rows?

Comment: yes - i mean that, and please post your model too - because i think that's the issue

Comment: @sintakonte it's over 2million, ok I will provide model

Answer (score 2):

You should use a cron job for this action. Create a cron job that runs each minute ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job ). There's no timeout for cronjobs.

I suggest the following functionalty:

When you press the "Generate CSV" button you can set a flag in the database to "true" and the cron job will start creating the CSV. Near the "Generate CSV" button you can create a hidden "Download CSV" button (will be initially hidden). When the process will be finished you can set the "Download CSV" to be visible (you can use ajax calls from javascript to check and find if the generate csv process was finished). The cron job will create/save the CSV to a pre-defined location, so the download button will just link (can be a "a href") to the csv location.

If you're using cron jobs make sure you have a database flag, such as "is_running" and when the generate process is running this flag is set to true (tinyint = 1) so no other generate csv process will start. When the process ends, set the flag to false (tinyint = 1).

Other option is to let the server to call this cron job each 60/30 minutes and display the download button from the very start. Each time the cron will run will update (delete/create) the same csv file.

Answer (score 1):

With over 2 Million rows - you've to make sure, that most data aren't in memory.

What you've to do here is the usage of the `unbuffered_row()` function

> you can find this function in the documentation under the unbuffered row section [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows)

```
public function createCSVExportFromCompanyTable($prefecture_id, $industry_id, $filter, $limit, $start)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('company'); 

    if ($filter) {
        $this->db->like('email','@');
    }

    if (!empty($prefecture_id) && $prefecture_id != 99) {
        $this->db->where('prefecture_id', $prefecture_id);
    }

    if (!empty($industry_id) && $industry_id != 99) {
        $this->db->where('industry_id', $industry_id);
    }

    if (!empty($limit)) {

        $this->db->limit($limit, $start); 
    }
    $this->db->order_by('prefecture_id, industry_id, offset');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 

    $delimiter = ",";

    //$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    $f = fopen('exportCompanyData.csv', 'w');

    $headerArray = array("id", "prefecture_id", "industry_id", "offset", "name", "email");

    fputcsv($f, $headerArray,$delimiter);

    while($row = $query->unbuffered_row())
    {
        $orig_email = $row->email;
        $mstring = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/",',',$orig_email);
        preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $mstring, $matches);
        $email = implode($matches[0]);

        $arrLine = [
            $row->id, $row->prefecture_id, $row->industry_id, $row->offset, preg_replace('/[,]/',' ',$row->name),$email
        ];

        fputcsv($f, $arrLine, $delimiter); 
    }
    fseek($f, 0);

    $csvFileName = "phpList_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".csv";

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$csvFileName.'";');
    fpassthru($f);

}
```

The only problem here could be the line `$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');`
due to memory issues;
If you still face memory issues try `$f = fopen('exportCompanyData.csv', 'w');`
instead.

> a last tip: @First try to run this function with at most 1k rows in
>   order to make sure the function is fine.

Be aware - i just wrote this code down - so i'm not sure if everything is syntactically correct - but the path should be clear and you should be able to work with this piece of code ;)

Comment: tried `$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');` but it still time-out, also tried `$f = fopen('exportCompanyData.csv', 'w');` it finished download but csv is empty.

Comment: i've tested it now - it works like a charm - even with 2 mio items - the only thing which is missing - is to set the time limit to 0 `set_time_limit(0);` - i've updated my code - but to be honest i assumed you would already know things like that, this feels like i should write an entire code for you because you are to lazy to think about that snippet .... (because if you would have used limit(1000) - you'would have seen this code works, but even that is to much to ask for...

Answer (score 0):

Try sample for inserting large data and increase your php timeout limit:

```
$data = array(
array( 'item' => 'Server', 'cost' => 10000, 'approved by' => 'Joe'),
array( 'item' => 'Mt Dew', 'cost' => 1.25, 'approved by' => 'John'),
array( 'item' => 'IntelliJ IDEA', 'cost' => 500, 'approved by' => 'James')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $fields) {
 if($i == 0){
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys($fields), 4800);// the number defines the buffer /bytes to be inserted at a time.
 }
  fputcsv($fp, array_values($fields));
  $i++;
}

fclose($fp);
```

and update your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
php_value memory_limit 256M 
</IfModule>
```